# How to save .bib file in latin1 encoding and avoid problems with special characters?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, input-encodings

I have added a lot of new references to my .bib file, which I got from online portals like sciencedirect.com.

I'm managing my .bib file with `JabRef 2.10`.

My bib file was encoded in latin1 (CP1252), because that worked well with my latex setup.

No with the new references I could not save my file any more because the encoding CP1252 can not display the following characters 
[image]

I then tried to save it in UTF8, which for sure worked well, but produced a lot of problems with my latex setup: if I understood correctly, I then have to use `biber` as `biblatex` backend and I had endless problems with compiling and was not able to get a working pdf file in the end. :-(

I even tried to change all my .tex files to utf8 as well to match them with the .bib files, but still I get errors with biber.
(One idea: I have some fields "annotate" with very much text in there, which might cause problems.)

So I want my CP1252 encoding back but I don't know how to find the problematic characters in my .bib file and replace them by something which CP1252 can process.

#### Question:

How can I identify the records with the problematic characters and replace those?
The bibtex file is very large (thousands of entries) and I don't see how to solve that, I've already lost hours of my (very short) time and don't see any hope.

Comment: Before anything, backup all your files.

Comment: Note `biber` is the default backend. I have no problems with it, except some (rare) times, the cache used by biber gets corrupted for some reason, which problem is easily solved by deleting the cache so biber builds a new one.

Comment: Biber is so great, it also provides the solution to this problem.  Try: `biber --tool --output_encoding=ascii mybib.bib` (or `latin1` or `cp1252` or...; and where 'mybib.bib' is your actual `.bib` file).  If there's a lesson here, it might well be that you should consider investing more effort into getting `biblatex` and `biber` up and running! Note that you may need to specify the input encoding too in your case: it is unclear what encoding your bibliography file now has.

Comment: @Jon: that gives me the error message "read_file '/var/folders/FX/FXr0KhAz2RWkK++BYv0W1++++TU/-Tmp-/par-6d626734/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/inc/lib/Biber/biber-tool.conf' - sysopen: No such file or directory at /var/folders/FX/FXr0KhAz2RWkK++BYv0W1++++TU/-Tmp-/par-6d626734/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/inc/lib/Biber/Config.pm line 341.
"

Comment: Is that a corrupted cache issue? Try `biber --cache` to see if the folders match. Is so, try removing it with the command `rm -rf \`biber --cache\``.

Comment: @jon: ok, after deleting the cache the conversion worked, but in the created .bib file there are many strange characters...

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question or opened a new one to explain precisely what you did and what the problem is. "many strange characters" is difficult to diagnose. Did `biber` rightly guess what the current encoding is? which output encoding did you choose? did you editor rightly recognize the new encoding? does the chosen target encoding in fact handle all the characters you need? etc., etc.

Comment: Imho the best way is: convert everything to utf8 (or find someone who does it for you). This is better than trying to force things back to an 8-bit encoding.

Comment: @jon: I'm sorry, if this was confusing. In fact you helped me a lot and indeed you are right the encoding seems to have worked - the "strange characters" resulted from the fact that JabRef assumed it was a UTF8 file instead of latin1. ... (mea maxima culpa).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I did that already (converting everything to utf8) and after tearing my hair and messing around a lot, now all my input files (.tex and .bib) are UTF-8, however I was not able to make it work with `biber`. But after going back to `backend=bibtex`, it suddenly worked again and I finally got a correct pdf file...

Comment: Ah, cheers! (Though I'm inclined to agree with Ulrike: UTF-8 is much better for the 'base' `.bib` file. Then use Biber to convert to other encodings as needed.)

Comment: @jon: I tried again with `biber`, but I get a lot of errors. Maybe they are caused by forbidden characters in my .bib file like % in abstracts etc. I tried to eliminate them, but I'm giving up. `bibtex` works so far and unfortunately I don't have the time to go even deeper. :-(

Comment: I wish I could help, but "get lots of errors" is impossible to fix without more information (which -- I totally understand -- you don't have time to worry about right now).

Comment: The real lesson here is to use version control....

Comment: @cfr: I **do** use version control for this `LaTeX` project, but I have 2 different repositories for literature and the latex files for "historical" reasons and I'm not an expert concerning the possibilities of `svn` unfortunately. Still there would be no problem going back to the older version.

Comment: @jon: thanks a lot, maybe we can solve this problem at a later time. Many of the errors contained `endcsname`. I researched that on the internet and found that other people had problems with characters like "%" in their bibtex entries. I also have those (very often in abstracts and sometimes even in the title :-(, as I have imported the information from the journal homepages) and I think they might be the problem, but I don't see how to fix that quickly. I also tried to ignore the abstract field (map_null), but that alone did not do the trick.

Comment: @jon: in parallel, I've been struggling for days now trying to fix our (other) PC with a dying hard disk and move the Windows (argh) OS to another disk and make it bootable. I'm under high pressure concerning time for my thesis project, but at the moment everything seems to go wrong. :-(

Comment: @Martin: Imho you are rushing and so run into problems. Your starting problems with the chars could have been easily solved by using commands like `\infty`, but you jumped with your whole thesis into utf8 and biber. It is easy (and doesn't take more than 1-2 hours even with a large document) to move everything to utf8 and biber - but not if one tries to do it in one go without knowledge. Do it in small steps. If you want to try out biber + utf8: start with a small test document and add your bib in small pieces.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks a lot - I know you are right, I'll try that way. In fact, with bibtex it does not work now either... :-( Working under high pressure always brings the risk of failure. I'll edit my question later as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jon for the hint:

It can be done with `biber` with the following command:

```
biber --tool --output_encoding=cp1252 mybib.bib
```

---

I got an error message first:

```
read_file '/var/folders/FX/FXr0KhAz2RWkK++BYv0W1++++TU/-Tmp-/par-6d626734/cache-a3cdad9231‌​6c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/inc/lib/Biber/biber-tool.conf' - sysopen: No such file or directory at /var/folders/FX/FXr0KhAz2RWkK++BYv0W1++++TU/-Tmp-/par-6d626734/cache-a3cdad92316‌​c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/inc/lib/Biber/Config.pm line 341.
```

the solution was to clean the biber cache:

```
rm -rf `biber --cache`
```